# Update .net core web app on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

I am developing a web app (web service) using Visual Studio 2015 net core v1 und hosting it on an Windows Server 2012 R2 with iis.

It is running well, but the changes I make are not being used.

In visual studio I save the changes and go to the publish section and publish it. I take the publish output folder and replace the original folder with it.

But it seems like it is not changing anything because I still get the old answers.

I tried restarting the website, but it did not change anything.

EDIT:
if I debug it, it works perfect

Comment: Could you please try to after publishing it in new folder? and also what changes you have done. if its in css/HTML clear the cache

Comment: I do not even have HTML/css at this point it is just the backend. Like a webservice

Comment: Just try it with publishing in another folder

Comment: using an other folder solved the problem. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Check the IIS binding in the original site is actually pointing to the folder you think it is

Comment: Some time copy/paste don't replace the files.  please update the answer with UP button :)

Comment: How are you consuming this webservice ? is it through an ajax call ? Or the webservice url only directly exposed? Have you also done any caching  inisde webservice ?

Comment: I'm ganna consume it with diffrent calls. mainly c# https and android https. no caching. it is more of an test/internal use right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Ankesh Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070560/ankesh-kumar) mentioned: selecting an other output folder solver this problem.